# Disable CSS for an element from a specific file

Tags: html, css

I am working on an existing code base that uses bootstrap. The existing code base has a single large CSS file (apart from bootstrap) that overrides many attributes from bootstrap.

I just want to disable all the CSS values from that large CSS file for a particular element.

```
largecss.css
<div disableCSSfromLargeCSS.css> </div>
```

Is this possible? Without manually checking the attributes and overriding them?

Comment: The only way I know of that would allow this is to include your HTML in an iframe, along with all the CSS you want to use (excluding the CSS you don't want to use). I know there's scoped CSS in the works, but that basically works the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

Try  $('#element *').removeAttr('style') or $('#element').children().removeAttr('style')  to remove all applied css to that div.

Comment: I want to keep the CSS from bootstrap but not from largecss.css